# Spring Boot Starter vs Spring Core?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm dealing with a legacy application that I am trying to upgrade its dependencies in its pom.xml (its a Java Spring project that uses Maven). The problem is, they didn't use any starters, and explicitly declared the dependencies like hibernate, spring-batch-core and stuff like that, that is declared in the spring-boot-starter parents.

My question is, I'm trying to replace all these individual dependencies and then I came across `spring-core` , and I didn't see it listed in the parent `spring-boot-starter` (2.4.4) pom. What is this used for and is it even needed for a Spring Boot project using Spring Web and Spring Batch?

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` (or use the tree view on the POM in Eclipse).

Comment: `spring-core` will basically be part of most starters as that includes classes/utilities/stuff used by most of the spring framework. So is it needed yes, do you need to declare it no you don't.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum  what confused me is , when I inspect the parent spring boot starter, I see all the 100+ dependencies, but I didn't see spring-core there, so I assumed we had to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Per, M. Deinum:

> spring-core will basically be part of most starters as that includes
> classes/utilities/stuff used by most of the spring framework. So is it
> needed yes, do you need to declare it no you don't. – M. Deinum 8
> hours ago